# Use Substring or Like operator to get result with left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am searching the solution for my problem but didn't get the right answer. So, I am deciding to write a question here. Please help me.

I have two tables

1. All_Records (This table contain explanation for all records along with key)
2. Usage_Table (This table contain all keys)

So, I need a query that shows the explanation of keys available in Usage_Table. For this I use Left Outer Join and my query

```
Select U.key, A.Explanation 
from Usage_Table U 
left outer join All_Records A on U.key = A.key
```

Above query work fine if the data is like

Usage_Table

```
Key   ---   
1.8.0
2.9.0
16.8.0
```

But now the situation turns like I have the keys with historical data like

```
1.8.0*12
1.8.0*13
1.8.0*14
```

Its not possible to add all keys and historical data keys in All_Records table.
But all historical keys have same explanation as original key.

So, I am stuck in query. I use LIKE operator or sub string. Sub String fails because key is not only 1.8.0 it may be 29.8.0 so the characters length may vary. Do you have any solution for this. Please help.  Looking forward to your response.

Comment: please add a tag with the DBMS you are using

Comment: @Mark, can you please more explain about your comment?

Comment: sql is only a language, then you can maybe use MySql, Oracle,... https://stackoverflow.com/tags/database/info

Comment: I am using MSSQL

Comment: Okay, done. I add the tag sql-server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Select U.key, A.Explanation 
from Usage_Table U left outer join
     All_Records A
     on U.key like A.key + '%';
```

Or, perhaps a more performant method would be to fix the key using a computed column:

```
alter table Usage_Table
    add key_correct as (left(key, charindex('*', key + '*') - 1);
```

You can then phrase the `join` as:

```
Select U.key, A.Explanation 
from Usage_Table U left outer join
     All_Records A
     on A.key = u.key_correct;
```

You can even add an index on `u.key_correct` to improve performance.